# Error installing APK INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED - Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

i'm having this error which can't let me install the apk on any device :

> Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.1" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.MainTabs"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.apphance.android.LAUNCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.TourInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tour_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.DiscoverTab"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_discover_tab_group" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.MyToursTab"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_tours_tab_group" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.SettingsTab"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_tab_group" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.Discover"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_discover" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.MyTours"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_tours" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.Topics"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_topics" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.Places"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_places" >
        </activity>

        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.example.ApphanceLauncherActivity"
            android:targetActivity="com.apphance.android.LauncherActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
                </action>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.apphance.android.LauncherActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.apphance.android.ui.LoginActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.apphance.android.ui.TestCycleActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.apphance.android.ui.ProblemActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <instrumentation
        android:name="com.apphance.android.ApphanceInstrumentation"
        android:targetPackage="com.example" >
    </instrumentation>

</manifest>
```

PS : I'm using Apphance API since a while and it never caused me problems.

**Edit :** I run once a project having the same package name by mistake, it caused me some errors in the second project so i changed it. Does it have any relation to the error in this project?

Any idea please?

Comment: Package Name in the Manifest is wrong in the Manifest tag it should be com.guidigo.activities

Comment: change activity-alias to activity

Comment: I don think so... i used to run the app as com.guidigo and no pb...

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj this is imposed by Apphance API i can't do otherwise

Comment: and this is not the problem, like a said i used to run this manifest no pb but i don know what happened...

Comment: your package name is mini just change it to com.guidigo.com for testing hope this will work and then you'll change according to yr requirement

Comment: same thing.. i changed it to com.guidigo.activities and nothing changed

Comment: after what you did, you are getting this error?
did u try cleaning the project?
if it does not work try close and reopen the eclipse

Comment: once you checked all package name and file name is correctly placed. i have error in past... and changed  these modification which i created in the project after that worked for me..

Comment: yes, i changed package name in all occurrences in the manifest, cleaned the workspace, and run again.. but i've got the same error again

Comment: should i mention that i've run once a project having the same package name, but only once. it caused some problems but i changed it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to Apphance API, when I placed the  tag as the last tag in  tag it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 5):

"An alias for an activity, named by the targetActivity attribute. The target must be in the same application as the alias and it must be declared before the alias in the manifest."

put LauncherActivity in front of ApphanceLauncherActivity

[activity-alias-element](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you development on you will check Eclipse Problem window. If tag error you have, see error line and description text in Problem window

Comment: there is no error in cat log, the error happens where i'm installing the APK

Comment: Android 2.1 OS doesn't support match_parent

Comment: Please say your target and minSdk version

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Answer (score 0):

Your package Name Should Start with small letters Not capital letters.

I solve this problem by start the package name with small letters >>> Trust me.